# How i can use custom pane in FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

I created custom pane

```
MyStackPane extends StackPane
```

When I use it in FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import application.MyStackPane?>

<MyStackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml>
    <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
</MyStackPane >
```

ClassNotFoundException throws.
How can i use it in FXML?

Comment: What does not work? Where does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing obviously wrong with the FXML you present.

Oracle have a tutorial for [creating a custom control and FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/custom_control.htm#BABDAAHE).  The tutorial links a [project with source code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/sample-apps/CustomControlExample.zip).  Read the tutorial, download the sample source and study it, then apply what you learned to your situation.  The sample is really a small amount of code, but I don't want post it here because its Oracle's.

Note, you can use your custom pane from FXML in SceneBuilder, see the [SceneBuilder documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/library-panel.htm).